# Django- Static HTML pages not loading if DB server is down

Tags: python, django

In my Django web application, there are many static HTML pages and there is no DB interaction required for these HTML pages. The problem is whenever DB server goes down, the whole site goes down. User cannot even see the static HTML pages.
Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: We cannot do anything for you if you do not provide any code.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following

Implement caching for your static HTML pages. You can use Django's built-in caching mechanisms to store rendered HTML content in memory or on disk. This way, if the database server is down, the cached HTML pages can still be served to users.
OR
Create an offline page that is completely separate from your Django application. This page could be a simple HTML file with the essential information that you want to display when the database server is down. When your application detects that the database is unavailable, you can redirect users to this offline page.